# Windows sdk 1903 ExtendViewIntoTitleBar issue

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I want to extend my app content to title bar, but
CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true; 
doesn't work.

When SDk version is 1809, it is normal, Then I update SDK version to 1903, it not work.

And if I down to 1809 or 1803, it is work. So I think it is a bug in 1903 SDK, not my code's fault.

---

update:

Ok, I tried it. It is NavigationView's issue.

In xaml:

```
<Page
x:Class="App1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App1"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="Black">

<Grid>
    <NavigationView 
        Background="Red" Header="asdasd">
        <Grid  >

            <CommandBar 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        DefaultLabelPosition="Right"
                        >
                <AppBarButton  Icon="Up"/>
                <AppBarButton  Icon="Shuffle"/>

            </CommandBar>
        </Grid>
    </NavigationView>

</Grid>
```

in App.xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        var coreTitleBar = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar;
        coreTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
```

Now run it, In 1809 version, Header extend to titlebar, like this image:
[image]

But in 1903, same code, same layout, just SDK version changed, header not into titlebar, and command bar go down too:

[image]

How to fix this? Thanks。

Comment: Thanks for your report. I've reported to the relevant team. They're investigating it.

Comment: Have you tried using the WinUI `NavigationView` instead of the built-in one? See https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml